# Android camera preview works only in 2 out of 3 phone orientations

Tags: android, camera, landscape, preview, activity-lifecycle

In my Android App I am using the Camera class to grab snapshots from the phone's camrea.
I use startPreview to start the camera preview and then takePicture to grab images.
I am forcing landscape on the App by adding

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

To AndroidManifest.xml.
The problem is when I return to my App when my phone is rotated 90 degrees counter clockwise. 
In this case, I cannot see the preview. It is either black or not set to the view. I can see the GUI and I can grab pictures from the phone properly. Everything works except the preview is not seen.
This does not happen when the phone is on portrait or when the phone is rotated 90 degrees clockwise.

So in short, preview is black when rotated to the left, but in other orinetations the preview is fine.

I have been banging my head on this for quite some time, but finally I discovered it's related to the phone's orientation before returning to the App.

Why my preview is not seen on that specific orinetation?

Edit: I have discovered something.
It's not the camera's fault per se, the GUI surfaceView I put above the camera preview somehow hides the preview.
I set it to have transparent background but it doesn't work, I also removed all the draw calls in the onDraw. But it still draws as black. It doesn't happen on the other orientations for some kind of a reason. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

what API lvl are you targeting?

If it is recent enough try changing `"landscape"` to `"sensorLandscape"`

I imagine that would get it worked out for you. However if you are targeting an API lvl that is too old you won't have this option.

Comment: No it doesn't work. Now my application can rotate between the two landscape orientations while running.
However, if I go back to the application from task manage, while it's rotated to the left, I still get a black preview. If I then rotate the phone to the right landscae, the preview is still black.(Although the GUI rotates nicely).
Now if I start with the task manager rotated to the right it also doesn't always work.
It works if I start off as portrait though.

Comment: hmm, that is my only idea really. Don't have much experience with the camera preview, sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: I have discovered something.
It's not the camera's fault per se, the GUI surfaceView I put above the camera preview somehow hides the preview.
I set it to have transparent background but it doesn't work, I also removed all the draw calls in the onDraw. But it still draws as black. It doesn't happen on the other orientations for some kind of a reason. Any idea?

Comment: @user1097185 I have a possibly related issue - when starting the camera preview and pressing the stand-by (or sleep/whatever) button on my SII (right side) the phone does to standby or sth. If I press the button again and unlock the screen, the camera preview is shown, but its all black - I thought it might have sth to do with the onPause/onResume implementation in my camera dialog... Maybe check there, whether you properly de/-reinitialize in pause/resume.